# Estimates for Law of Large number

Tags: probability-theory

In many literature it has been state that the necessary condition that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges almost surely is that $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges to 0 almost surely. (where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$) However, I fail to see why.

It is easy to see that $\frac{X_n}{n}=\frac{S_n}{n}-\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1}$. So if n tends to infinity, $\frac{S_n}{n}$ and $\frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1}$ converges to the same quantity. But what happens with the factor $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Is there a nice way to prove $\frac{X_n}{n}$ tends to zero?

Another question I have is, $\frac{X_n}{n}$ tends to zero is a necessary condition for $\frac{S_n}{n}$ convergence. Is it also sufficient? If yes, how can I see that? If not, what would be the sufficient condition?

Comment: Doesn't $\frac{n-1}{n} \to 1$?

Comment: @aduh argh Stupid question. I was concerned that they might cause some unexpectable effect with the latter term.

Comment: Note that, if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{a_i}$ converges, then $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} a_i = 0$. However, the reverse implication is not valid.  You can use the same type of counter-example.

Comment: @madprob What would be sufficient condition? My problem is, in practice the convergence of $\frac{X_n}{n}$ can be easier determined by borel cantelli lemma than the sum $\frac{S_n}{n}$. How can I use the information of $\frac{X_n}{n}$ to investigate the convergence for $\frac{S_n}{n}$. For non-convergence it is easy as one can express the difference of two consecutive sequences $\frac{S_{n+1}}{n+1}$ and $\frac{S_n}{n}$ in terms of $\frac{X_n}{n}$. How would it work if I want have convergence?

Comment: Are $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ i.i.d.? This would make the problem much easier. Are they independent?

Comment: @madprob yes sorry, just the usual assumption on SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question has nothing to do with probability: if $s_n = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$ and $s_n / n$ converges to $\ell$, then

$$ \frac{a_n}{n} = \frac{s_n}{n} - \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{s_{n-1}}{n-1} \xrightarrow[\quad n\to\infty \quad]{} \ell - (1 \cdot \ell) = 0. $$

This is because $\frac{n-1}{n}$ converges to $1$ and product of convergent sequences converges to the product of the respective limits.

For your second question, the answer is YES, assuming that $(X_n)$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. In this case, we have the following observation:

> **Proposition.** The followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X_1$ is integrable.
> 2. $X_n/n$ converges to $0$ almost surely.

The proof is standard in view of the Borel-Cantelli lemmas. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
X_n/n \to 0 \quad\text{a.s.}
&\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \forall \epsilon > 0 \ : \ \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq \epsilon n \text{ i.o.}) = 0 \\
&\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \forall \epsilon > 0 \ : \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq \epsilon n) < \infty \\
&\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \mathbb{E}|X_1| < \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: How can I see that $S_n/n$ then converges if X_1 is integrable? So I need the strong law of large number to close the argument? Is it also chance to proof it without the strong law of large number?

Comment: @quallenjäger, Of course you need SLLN to close the argument.

Comment: Thanks. This has been very helpful.

Comment: @quallenjäger, Glad it helped :)